# Is there a way to have a particular set of styling for one row of a data table?

Tags: html, css

I am populating my table with ng-repeat, I want to have a specific indentation for specific row elements in the table, is it possible to have a different padding for different rows of a data table?

HTML:

```html
<td ng-class = "{indent :true}" ></td>
```

CSS:

```css
.indent { 
  padding:0px;
}
```

The element of the table takes in the default styling of the table which is present in the table tbody tr td CSS class.

Comment: Could you please provide minimal working example to show your table and what you wish to achieve?

Comment: <td ng-class = "{indent :true}" ></td> the css has the following code..indent { padding:0px;}. But the element of the table takes in the default styling of the table which is present in.table tbody tr td css class

Answer (score 1):

Essentially:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .padder td {
                padding:10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr class="padder">
            <td>I have padding</td>
            <td>I have padding</td>
            <td>I have padding</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>I don't have padding</td>
            <td>I don't have padding</td>
            <td>I don't have padding</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>I don't have padding</td>
            <td>I don't have padding</td>
            <td>I don't have padding</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Or without a class `table tr:first-child td { padding:10px; }` https://jsfiddle.net/cyLbopkd/

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, howsoever I am populating my table with ng-repeat. So I need to have a conditional padding styling based on a value.

Comment: @user2019135 don't you think that `I am populating my table with ng-repeat` is important information which should be mentioned in the question?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by applying padding to all `<td>` tags in the row. Like this:

```css
        .first {
            padding:10px;
        }
        .second {
            padding:20px;
        }
        .third {
            padding:30px;
        }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="first">first</td>
        <td class="first">first</td>
        <td class="first">first</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="second">second</td>
        <td class="second">second</td>
        <td class="second">second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="third">third</td>
        <td class="third">third</td>
        <td class="third">third</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment information which would be important for the question but anyways you might be looking for something like this:

```css
td[ng-class="{indent :true}"] {
  padding:10px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cyLbopkd/1/

```css
td[ng-class="{indent :true}"] {
  padding:10px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-class="{indent :true}">Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my system, I am using bootstrap 2.2.0. And one more question, I have a boolean expression in place for true, how would my css evaluate the boolean expression?